# How to query distinct dates in HQL

Tags: hibernate, date, hql, distinct

I have a table that has a column creation_time of type timestamp in postgres. In one of my classes I need to retrieve all the distinct creation times using HQL. I've tried different queries like:

```
select distinct cast(creation_time as date) from Product;
```

but it always returns list of Product objects!. Then I've tried this one:

```
select year(pr.creationTime),month(pr.creationTime), day(pr.creationTime) from Product as pr;
```

but this one also didn't work it gives this error:

```
function year(timestamp without time zone) does not exist
```

Any help in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use

```
select distinct to_char(creation_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy') from Product;
```